# Why do I need to use Wait when Sending email using SendGrid C# client library in a console app

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, sendgrid

I am using the C# client library for SendGrid version 9.27.0.

The only way I can get it to send an email is by adding `Wait()` to end of my method.

I understand the `await` operator is a promise to return back to the point in code after the asynchronous method is finished.

But why do I need to add `Wait()`?   Isn't that converting the asynchronous method to synchronous?  If so, what's the point in making it async?

**Program.cs**

```cs
static void Main(string[] args) {
    //var customerImport = new CustomerImport();
    //customerImport.DoImport();

    var mailClient = new MailClient();
    var recipients = new List<string>();
    recipients.Add("test@lobbycentral.com");

    //Never sends an email
    var response = mailClient.SendMail("noreply@lobbycentral.com", recipients, "Test email", "This is a test of the new SG client", false);

    //Will send an email
    mailClient.SendMail("noreply@lobbycentral.com", recipients, "Test email", "This is a test of the new SG client", false).Wait();
}
```

**MailClient.cs**

```cs
public async Task SendMail(string emailFrom, List<string> emailTo, string subject, string body, bool isPlainText) {

    try {
        var apiKey = Utils.GetConfigValue("sendgridAPIKey");
        var emails = new List<EmailAddress>();

        foreach (string email in emailTo) {
            emails.Add(new EmailAddress(email));
        }

        var plainTextContent = "";
        var htmlContent = "";

        if (!isPlainText) {
            htmlContent = body;
        } else {
            plainTextContent = body;
        }

        var message = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmailToMultipleRecipients(new EmailAddress(emailFrom, "LobbyCentral"), emails, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);

        //if (metaData != null)
        //    message.AddCustomArgs(metaData);

        foreach (string filename in FileAttachments) {
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(filename)) {
                using (var filestream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filename)) {
                    await message.AddAttachmentAsync(filename, filestream);
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (PlainTextAttachmentM plainTextM in PlainTextAttachments) {
            byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(plainTextM.Content);

            var attachment = new Attachment();
            attachment.Content = Convert.ToBase64String(byteData);
            attachment.Filename = plainTextM.AttachmentFilename;
            attachment.Type = "txt/plain";
            attachment.Disposition = "attachment";

            message.AddAttachment(attachment);
        }
        
        var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
        var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(message);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {

            if (DeleteAttachmentsAfterSend && FileAttachments.Count > 0) {
                foreach (string filename in FileAttachments) {
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists(filename)) {
                        System.IO.File.Delete(filename);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            Utils.DebugPrint("error sending email");
        }


    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new Exception(string.Format("{0}.{1}: {2} {3}", System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.FullName, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace));
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense and is clear.   In our web application the code works without Wait, but I'm assuming that is because it is always running in the Application pool.  Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `mailClient.SendMail` **starts a `Task`, but doesn't wait for its completion.**

If that's the last instruction of you program, the program simply ends before the tasks can finish.

You want your last instructions to start **and wait** for the task's completion. You can do that by using either of the following.

Make your `Main` async. (That's what I would personally do.)

```cs
// Signature changed to async Task instead of void.
static async Task Main(string[] args) {
        // (...)
        
        // Added await. Removed Wait.
        await mailClient.SendMail("noreply@lobbycentral.com", recipients, "Test email", "This is a test of the new SG client", false);
}
```

Use `Wait` like you're doing.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args) {
        // (...)
        
        var task = mailClient.SendMail("noreply@lobbycentral.com", recipients, "Test email", "This is a test of the new SG client", false);
        task.Wait();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Question :** But why do I need to add `Wait()`? Isn't that converting the asynchronous method to synchronous? If so, what's the point in making it async?

**Answer :** It's not **mandatory** to `Wait()` a `Task`. *What's the point in making it async*? It gives you two great benefits.

1. You can return `Task`, which means it's awaitable, and which means again, you can choose either wait it or just forget about it and let the task scheduled and picked up by a threadPool thread instead of synchronously running it in the same thread.
2. You can use `async/await` pattern, which means you can gracefully avoid blocking the current thread

Below code obviously will block the current thread.

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    .
    .
    //Will send an email
    mailClient.SendMail("noreply@lobbycentral.com", recipients, "Test email", "This is a test of the new SG client", false)
   .Wait(); // <- block the current thread until the task completes.
}
```

If `SendMail` is something you can fire&forget in *your real codebase*, you can just get rid of `.Wait()` and move on without checking the `Task` state.  But your application should be up and running for a certain, enough time to finish the scheduled task. If it's not, you'd better think of using `async/await` pattern instead of blocking your valuable thread by using `.Wait()`.

```
static async Task Main(string[] args) 
{
    .
    .
    //Will send an email and get to know when the task is done.
    await mailClient.SendMail("noreply@lobbycentral.com", recipients, "Test email", "This is a test of the new SG client", false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to await it in *this* console app because the very last thing that the Main() does before it returns (and the app exits) is send the mail. I'd say there is slim to no chance at all that the mail sending task will complete before the app exits; it involves a lot of IO, whereas it will take nanoseconds for the app to quit, taking the incomplete Task with it

Anything you do to make it wait long enough will suffice; turning it synchronous with a call to Wait, making the Main as `async Task Main(...)`, even adding a Console.ReadLine will all mean the mail sending will have time to complete ..

.. though I question why a console app that only does one thing then exits even needs to be async anything - it simply has no other jobs to do while it waits for this IO to complete so there seems little point using any asyncronous facilities

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**
Update your code to use `async`, `await`, and `Task`'s throughout the whole call chain of your method, including your `Main` method, otherwise your program won't wait for the asynchronous `Task`'s to complete and will not run all your code.

Your code should look like this:

```cs
static async Task Main(string[] args) {
    //var customerImport = new CustomerImport();
    //customerImport.DoImport();

    var mailClient = new MailClient();
    var recipients = new List<string>();
    recipients.Add("test@lobbycentral.com");

    //Never sends an email
    var response = await mailClient.SendMail("noreply@lobbycentral.com", recipients, "Test email", "This is a test of the new SG client", false);
}
```

---

In C# .NET the `Task` class represents an operation that usually is performed asynchronously on another thread. When you use the `await` keyword or the `.Wait()` method, the program will wait for the operation to finish and then continue executing the next statements.

The difference between using the `await` keyword and the `.Wait()` method is that the `await` keyword will release the current thread so other work can be done on the current thread, while the `.Wait()` method will block the current thread, leaving the thread unutilized until the task is complete.
When the task is complete, when using the `async` keyword, the program will find an available thread (not necessarily the same thread as you started on) and will continue to run the instructions subsequent to your `await`. The `.Wait()` blocks the current thread, so it'll keep using the current thread when the task is complete.

To use `await` you need to make your method `async`. Sometimes, you don't need to wait on the `Task` and you can simply return it, in that case you don't need to mark the method as `async` although it is still recommended for easier debugging.
However, once you start using `async` and `Task`'s, you need to do so all the way up to the call chain.

This sample using `.Wait` needs to be converted to using `async`/`await`.

```cs
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DoSomeWork();
    }

    public static void DoSomeWork()
    {
        DoFileOperations();
    }

    public static void DoFileOperations()
    {
        File.ReadAllTextAsync("/path/to/file").Wait();
    }
}
```

Making this program asynchronous looks like this:

```cs
public static class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await DoSomeWork();
    }

    public static Task DoSomeWork()
    {
        // you can return a Task without awaiting it, as a result no need for async keyword.
        return DoFileOperations();
        
        // But the following is recommended for easier debugging, at cost of a negligible performance hit. (Also need to mark method is async for this)
        // return await DoFileOperations(); 
    }

    public static async Task DoFileOperations()
    {
        await File.ReadAllTextAsync("/path/to/file");
    }
}
```

For a console program, you need to update the `Main` method signature to use `async Task` or `Task` for this to work. If you don't, the `Task` will start running but the program will exit immediately and not wait for the `Task` to be complete.

(Non-console applications will provide other APIs to do `async`/`await`.)

In your application, your `Main` method does not have the `async Task` or `Task` return signature, and you're not awaiting the `Task` returned from the `mailClient.SendMail` method.

What likely is happening inside of your `mailClient.SendMail` method is

1. The first asynchronous `Task` is started, created by the `message.AddAttachmentAsync`
2. This `Task` runs on a separate thread, meanwhile the current thread goes back to run the code after `mailClient.SendMail` in the `Main` method
3. The `Main` method finishes and the console application stops running.

At this point, the `Task` from `message.AddAttachmentAsync` is likely finished already, but the subsequent code is never run, including the `client.SendEmailAsync` method, because the `Task` from `mailClient.SendMail` wasn't awaited.

There's a lot more nuance to `async`, `await`, and `Task`'s, but those details aren't too relevant to your questions, so if you're interested, here's [more info on Asynchronous programming with async and await from the Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/).
I'd also recommend reading [David Fowler's guidance on async/await](https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md) which lists some pitfalls and best practices.